# Include a library service or API into my springboot component

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Someone has created a springboot component/application to handle errors and turned it into a library.

I need to include/call it in my springboot application/component and use it in the following way:

wherever i catch an exception i should define an error code and pass it to the library and then the library should return me the description of that specific error code.

How do i achieve this?

The library code is if below

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ErrorHandlingController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private ErrorHandlingService errorHandlingService;

    @ResponseStatus
    @RequestMapping("err/{errorCode}")
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionDetailsOutputEntity> getErrorByID(@PathVariable int errorCode) throws GenericEntityNotFoundException {

       try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(errorHandlingService.retrieveExceptionDetails(errorCode));
        } catch (GenericEntityNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
           return ResponseEntity.ok(errorHandlingService.retrieveExceptionDetails(ErrorMessageEnum.Error_not_defined));
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "ERROR_MESSAGES")
public class ExceptionDetailsOutputEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int errorCode;
    private String userMessage;
    private String message;
    ......;

}
```

```
@Data
public class ErrorLogLayout implements Serializable {

    private  String applicationName ;
    private  String serverName ;
    .......
    ...

}
```

```
@Service
public interface ErrorHandlingService {

    ExceptionDetailsOutputEntity retrieveExceptionDetails(int errorCode) throws GenericEntityNotFoundException;
}
```

Service implementation

```
@Service
public class ErrorHandlingServiceImpl implements ErrorHandlingService {

    @Autowired
    ErrorHandlingRepoitory errorHandlingRepoitory;


     @Override
    public ExceptionDetailsOutputEntity retrieveExceptionDetails(int errorCode) throws GenericEntityNotFoundException {
        logger.debug("Inside retrieveExceptionDetails service ");
        try {
           errorDetailsResponse = errorHandlingRepoitory.findByErrorCode(errorCode);
            if(errorDetailsResponse!=null){
             if (errorDetailsResponse.getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase(ERROR_CATEGORY)
                    || errorDetailsResponse.getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase(ERROR_CAT)) {
               errorLoggingMapping(errorDetailsResponse);
             }
        }else{
                retrieveGenericError();
                errorLoggingMapping(errorDetailsResponse);
            }
                return errorDetailsResponse;
        } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new GenericEntityNotFoundException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void writeToaFile(ErrorLogLayout layout) throws IOException {
        File filePath = new File("/opt/ErrorLoggingLogs/ ");
        FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(filePath + "error.log" + "." + getDateFormat(), true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fr);
        out.write(String.valueOf(layout));
        out.newLine();
        out.close();
        fr.close();
     }

    public void errorLoggingMapping(ExceptionDetailsOutputEntity errorDetailsResponse) throws GenericEntityNotFoundException {
        try {
            ErrorLogLayout layout = new ErrorLogLayout();
            layout.setErrorCode(errorDetailsResponse.getErrorCode());
            .....
            ...
        }catch(IOException io){
            throw new GenericEntityNotFoundException(io.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private String getDateFormat(){
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") ;
        String curDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        return curDate;
    }

   private void retrieveGenericError(){
        errorDetailsResponse = new ExceptionDetailsOutputEntity();
        errorDetailsResponse.setErrorCode(ErrorMessageEnum.Error_not_defined);
        .....
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell how you can do that without seeing the library's code or its documentation if you have those and could add to the post together with what you have tried, then it will be a lot easier to help you out :)

Comment: okay i will update my question and include the library's code